# Остановка скролинга при касании экрана

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток.
Суть вопроса в следующем. Есть **UIScrollView** с кастомным paging, после свайпа если нажать еще раз на двигающийся скролл он останавливается на моменте нажатия. Подскажите пожалуйста как это отключить?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Даже не могу представить для чего это нужно, но можно попробовать после свайпа задать

[yourScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

Comment: Попробую, спасибо. Вопрос поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Задайте делегат `UIScrollViewDelegate`  и определите в нем следующие методы:

```
- (void) scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```